# Copy cell in a row if it matches column name

Tags: r

I searched for a while to try to solve this, but unfortunately couldn't find an answer.

In my dataframe, the last column contains strings which match column names. I would like to create another column that for each row returns(copies) the value that matches that column name.

For example, say my data is:

```
col1 <- c(1, 4, 6, 0, 5)
col2 <- c(4, 6, 7, 8, 6)
col3 <- c(0, 4, 2, 2, 1)
col4 <- c("col1", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col1")
df <- data.frame(col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

and what I want to achieve is col5 which copies relevant cells from each row:

```
col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
1     4     0     col1  1
4     6     4     col1  4
6     7     2     col2  7
0     8     2     col3  2
5     6     1     col1  5
```

Basically it looks at col4 and returns the value from the same row that matches that column name.

This is obviously a very simplified version of my data which is why I'd like to automate it. 
I would really appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `row/col` indexing to extract the elements from the dataset to create the 'col5'.

```
df$col5 <- df[-4][cbind(1:nrow(df), match(as.character(df$col4), colnames(df)))]
df$col5
#[1] 1 4 7 2 5
```

Comment: It worked!!! Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help! Will accept as an answer in a couple of minutes when I'm allowed to :)